# Power calculation for a three condition between-subject counterbalanced linear mixed model with an additional within-subject factor

Tags: r, mixed-model, statistical-power, counterbalancing

#### Problem

Hey, i need some help for power calculation for a *three condition counterbalanced linear mixed model with an additional within-subject factor*. This is an fictious example, which doesn't make a lot of the sense, but the design we want to use is equal. We assume that stimuli are nested within participants, since all participants are  exposed to the same 5 stimuli (photos of 5 people's faces) apart from the experimental variation (neutral or aggressive face expression) of these stimuli. I want to include random intercepts for participants and abstracts.

#### Variables

###### Factor "condition": Three Between-Subject Levels

1. Medication = "med"
2. Psychotherapy = "psych"
3. Control Group = reference group

###### Factor Emotional Expression in Stimulus "expression": 2 Within-Subject Levels

1. Aggresive = 1
2. Neutral = 0

###### Stimulus "stim"

Pictures of faces from 5 different people in 2 different emotional expressions 'Neutral' or 'Aggressive'. Randomized Order, replacement = FALSE. 5 people * 2 expressions = 10 pictures.

###### Dependent Variable "startle"

Metric Variable: 5 measurement points of measuring an individuals startle reflex

#### Design

| Condition | t1 | t2 | t3 | t4 | t5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Medication | stim 1/2/3/4 OR 5 & neu/agg | stim 1/2/3/4 OR 5 & neu/agg | stim 1/2/3/4 OR 5 & neu/agg | stim 1/2/3/4 OR 5 & neu/agg | stim 1/2/3/4 OR 5 & neu/agg |
| Psychotherapy | stim 1/2/3/4 OR 5 & neu/agg | stim 1/2/3/4 OR 5 & neu/agg | stim 1/2/3/4 OR 5 & neu/agg | stim 1/2/3/4 OR 5 & neu/agg | stim 1/2/3/4 OR 5 & neu/agg |
| Control Group | stim 1/2/3/4 OR 5 & neu/agg | stim 1/2/3/4 OR 5 & neu/agg | stim 1/2/3/4 OR 5 & neu/agg | stim 1/2/3/4 OR 5 & neu/agg | stim 1/2/3/4 OR 5 & neu/agg |

#### Model

The model i want to fit should look like this:

```r
lmer(startle ~ med + psych + expression + med * expression + psych +
expression +(1|participant) + (1|stim), data=dat)
```

### Power Parameters

condition: eta sqaured = 0.06;
expression: d = 0.4;
Power = 0.8;

How could I do a Power Analysis for this counterbalanced purpose? What would be an appropriate power analysis?

I am aware of [Westfall and Judd's](https://jakewestfall.shinyapps.io/two_factor_power/) online power analysis for Counterbalanced Linear Mixed Model. But it doesn't include a further between-subject factor and it includes random slopes by default.

Tools like G*Power are also not flexible enough for designs like this.

Comment: You need to use simulations. In R, simr is a good and flexible package for power simulations for multilevel models. With the function makeLmer, you can specify the model you wish to test.

Comment: Thank you very much! Great package (: